# The statement if combobox selectedindex == 1 || 2 gives a syntax error in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making human to animal year converter.

My code:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || 2)
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

I get the following error :

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Comment: I did get my answer thx

Comment: You can write an extension method to make it look like `if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex.In(1, 2))`. Less duplication that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the above expression like this

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || 2)
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

You have to use it in the following way:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2 )
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Problem:** Your `if` condition, which you thought would resolve to:

```
comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2
```

Actually resolves to:

```
(comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1) || (2)
```

**Reason:** The equality operator (`==`) has more precedence than the conditional OR operator (`||`).

**More info:** [MSDN: C# Operator Precedence and Associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

The first part of `(comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1) || (2)` returns a value of type `bool` while the second of type `int`.

**Hence the error:**

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

**Resolution:** You should clearly specify the condition as:

```
comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to check make an OR operation on boolean (left side, comparison operator) and an integer number (right side, just a number).

OR (||) has to be applied on two booleans values.

So you should do something like that:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

**Reference:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6373h346.aspx#fbid=5K95u5HbB8E

Answer (score 4):

The logical or operator (||) is used to do a logical or on boolean values.
In a natural language like english you say

> "It should be blue or red"

but what you really mean is

> "It should be blue or it should be red"

Same thing with computers. They can only evaluate on complete expressions, not on shortcuts.

Try the following instead:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex==2)
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

The first part of the if condition evaluates a boolean value if the index is 1, the second part evaluates to a boolean value if the index is 2. The logical or operator combines these two values and return s true if one of the or both are true.

Answer (score 3):

you are doing it wrong because for second `condition` after `OR` `Operator` you are missing first `operand` . try this code

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex==2)
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  this  `if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex==2)`

instead of  `if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || 2)`

[**|| Operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6373h346.aspx#fbid=5K95u5HbB8E)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to true or false.

---

```
 if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex==2)
    {
       comboBox3.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it somewhat more elegant and flexible, have this:

```
comboBox3.Visible = (new[] { 1, 2 }).Contains(comboBox2.SelectedIndex);
```

This way you can add as many possible values as you want without adding another condition for each.

If you don't want to set the visibility to false but just to  true when condition is met, you can have:

```
comboBox3.Visible = (new[] { 1, 2 }).Contains(comboBox2.SelectedIndex) ? true : comboBox3.Visible;
```

Comment: Cool, but this is not the same: If SelectedIndex is not 1 or 2, Visible is set to false. This may not be intended.

Comment: @helb maybe, but usually it will be set to false by default anyway, and visible only if condition is met so this will have same impact. Edited just to make sure all corners are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators can be used only between two boolean values. But in your case the first one is an Boolean value and the second one is taken as an integer as you have not written any condition there.

So, write the following statement

```
if ((comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1) || (comboBox2.SelectedIndex==2))
{
   comboBox3.Visible = true;
}
```